# EWS - How to get isRecurring info in GetItemResponse

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, ewsjavaapi

I am using EWS API in Java for Exchange Server communication. I have subscribed to Exchange server with stream subscription for Calendar folder. I am getting notifications when a meeting is created and sent to me. I wonder, if I can learn in the code the `isRecurring` data for this meeting. When I use `getUserAvailability` service, it provides this data. Can I get it also in my structure?

For `ItemEvents`:

```
// Now retrieve the Subject property of all the new mails in one call to EWS
ServiceResponseCollection<GetItemResponse> responses = service.bindToItems(
                       newMailsIds,
                       new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.MimeContent, ItemSchema.Body));

System.out.println("count=======" + responses.getCount());

for(GetItemResponse response : responses)
{
  System.out.println("count=======" + response.getClass().getName());
  System.out.println("subject=======" + response.getItem().getSubject());
  System.out.println("body=======" + response.getItem().getBody());
  System.out.println("mimecontent=======" + response.getItem().getMimeContent().toString());

  //Iterator itr = response.getItem().getExtendedProperties().iterator();
  //while (itr.hasNext()) 
  //{
  //    System.out.println("ExtendedProperties=======" + itr.next().toString());
  //}
}
```

Comment: I only know the raw XML in the reponse; there's a *<Recurrence>* item in it. Don't you have that as a property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa580471%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

As you are subscribing to Calendar-Folder only, then instead you can directly bind it to Appointment object ::

```
  Appointment appointment = Appointment.bind(service, itemEvent.getItemId() , 
                     new PropertySet( AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Body,AppointmentSchema.IsRecurring ) );
```